# I guess tradingview has big bug, why this code dose not act correctly

Tags: pine-script

I wrote this code

```
len = input(5, minval = 1, title = "MA Length")
src = input(ohlc4, title = "MA Source")
longlevel1 = input(-13.0, title = "Long line 1")
needoffset = input(true, title = "Offset")
size = strategy.position_size
ma = sma(src, len)
longline1 = (ma * ((100 + longlevel1) / 100))
colorlong1 = color.lime
offset = needoffset ? 1 : 0
plot(ma, offset = offset, color = color.blue, title = "MA line")
plot(longline1, offset = offset, color = colorlong1, title = "Long line 1")
lot = 0.0
lot := size == 0 ? strategy.equity / close : lot[1]
lots = 0.0
lots := round(size / lot)
if (lots<=1 and close[1]>longline1)
strategy.order("L1", strategy.long, lot, limit = longline1)

strategy.exit(id="L1", from_entry="L1", limit = ma)
```

but when close[1] is lower than longline1[1], it opens positions   what should I do?

look at to the picture below.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/VNb9ioWj/

Please consider this and explain to me why it happens?!

for example it should not open second long position at Feb 15th. Because the previous bar closed under longline1, but it opened a new long!!!

Answer (score 0):

is not a bug
you can control your position size by define global variable from Previous candle. also you can limit open position count by strategy.position_size

```html
if (lots<=1 and close[1] > longline1 and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.order("L1", strategy.long, lot, limit = longline1)
```

Comment: I did exactly that. (lots<=1 and close[1] > longline1). The problem is that the Trading View platform has ignored my precondition (close[1] > longline1) and opened a new position. https://www.tradingview.com/x/VNb9ioWj/. Please click on the link and see the image.    In fact, the problem is that I want to define stop loss on this strategy. Whenever it falls below the line, it takes a long position, but if, for example, it loses 4%, it closes and does not open a new position while it is below the line, but trading view behaves stupidly. And opens a new position, which practically defeats STLOSS